# Bootstrap 3.1.1 - Navbar customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a help to customize the navbar on the page http://getbootstrap.com/customize/:

1. set the `height` of navbar to `67px`;
2. set the vertical align for the navbar content to `center`

Is it possible via the customization page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it possible, you can change next variables:

```
  @navbar-height: 67px
  @navbar-padding-vertical: ((@navbar-height - @line-height-computed) / 2) - 2
```

Answer (score 2):

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

you have a field @navbar-height and for the vertical align I didn't see any customization option